# Ethernet card with gigabit and 10GbE ports?

Tags: networking, pcie

I swear I have seen such a card before but it's proving impossible to Google :( I believe it had two gigabit ports and a 10GbE.

Comment: It feels unlikely simply cause it'd need a PLX chip to split between two different ethernet chips. That said, was it copper or SFP+?

Comment: The gigabit half was RJ45, I am not 100% of the ten gigabit half.

Comment: gigabit's always RJ45. 10GBe - copper was uncommon until recently. And it dosen't quite ring a bell to me. I'd be curious about such a thing tho :D

Comment: SFP exists for gigabit so it's not always RJ45.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not the most exact what you are searching for, but this is the closest that I got: [https://www.amazon.com/10Gtek-X540-T2-Converged-Network-Adapter/dp/B01HMGWOU8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HMGWOU8)

It has 2 ethernet ports, both of which support both 10 gigabit and 1 gigabit, so you can connect 2 1gigabit cables, 1 10gigabit and 1 1gigabit cable, or 2 10gigabit cables. It also uses standard RJ-45 connectors, so you can also connect it with standard routers and switches.

Comment: I have one of these - they're 'obsolete' so cheap as chips. I would warn though, they have a reputation for running rather hot. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000966074992.html is the same card, though a chinese OEM, and it runs great in initial testing

Comment: Oh also, if you're running a 'mixed' network, unlike newer cards, these won't drop down to 2.5GBe. I've also gotten good benchmarks on these with jumbo frames (which needs to be supported across the network) and cat 5e (which is fine for short runs.)